# Asynchronously wait for output from a comint process

Tags: subprocess, comint, async

First of all, a disclaimer. I have researched this many times, and I
am pretty sure that I have already found the answer one way or
another, but I just don't understand it.

My problem is the following:

- I have a process running through comint
- I want to send a line of input, capture output and see when it is
  over (when the last line of the output matches the regexp for a
  prompt)
- only when the process has finished sending output, I want to send
  another line of input (for example).

For a bit of background, think of a major mode implementing
interaction with a program, which may return an arbitrary amount of
output, in arbitrarily long time. This should not be an unusual
situation, right? Okay, maybe the part where I need to wait *between*
inputs is unusual, but it has a few advantages over sending the input
as a whole:

- the output buffer is nicely formatted: input output input
  output...
- more importantly, when sending a lot of text to a process, the text
  is cut into pieces and the pieces are pasted back by the process;
  the cutting points are arbitrary and this sometimes makes invalid
  input (my process won't paste back correctly an input cut in
  the middle of an identifier, for example)

Anyway, unusual or not, it turns out that it *is* complicated. Right now,
I am using something along the lines of

```
(defun mymode--wait-for-output ()
  (let ((buffer (mymode-get-buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (forward-line 0)
      (while (not (mymode-looking-at-prompt))
        (accept-process-output nil 0.001)
        (redisplay)
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (forward-line 0))
      (end-of-line))))
```

and I call this every time after sending an input line, and before
sending the next one. Well... it works, that's already something.

But it also makes emacs hang
while waiting for the output. The reason is obvious, and I figured
that if I included some kind of asynchronous `sleep-for` (for
example 1s) in the loop it would delay the output by 1s, but suppress
the hanging. Except that it seems that this kind of asynchronous
`sleep-for` *doesn't exist*.

Or does it? More generally, is there an idiomatic way of achieving
this with emacs? In other words:

**How to send input to a process, wait for the output, then send more input, asynchronously?**

When searching around (see the related questions), I have mainly seen
mentions of sentinels (but I don't think it applies in my case, since
the process doesn't finish) and of some comint hooks (but then what?
should I make the hook buffer-local, turn my "evaluate the remaining
lines" into a function, add this function to the hook and clean the
hook afterwards? that sounds really dirty, doesn't it?).

I am sorry if am not making myself clear, or if there is really an
obvious answer available somewhere, I am really confused by all the
intricaties of process interaction.

If needed, I can make this all a working example, but I am afraid that
it would just make one more "specific process question with specific
process answer" like all those I found earlier and didn't help me.

**Some related questions on SO:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/16815598/1083706
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3572532/1083706
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6578373/1083706

Comment: @nicael What's wrong about the related links?

Comment: But why do you need to include them?

Comment: Well, I have found them to be related questions, even if the answers didn't help me. If someone wants to help me, presumably they will have a deeper knowledge of the matter than I have, but maybe they will still need to perform a research beforehand. In this case, the questions give them some starting point. And additionally, if someday someone lands on this page but with a problem more alike the ones I linked to, they will have a shortcut to the appropriate question.

Comment: @nicael (Forgot to ping in the first post, sorry) Is it a problem that the links aren't from m-x.sx?

Comment: Ok. You can roll back to your revision, its your post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `accept-process-output` if you want asynchronous processing. Emacs will accept output every time when it is waiting for user input.

The proper way to go is to use filter functions to intercept the output. You don't need to create or delete the filter(s) depending on whether you still have lines to send. Rather, you will usually declare a single filter for the lifetime of the process and use buffer-local variables to track the state and do different things as needed.

#### The low-level interface

[Filter functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html#Filter-Functions) are what you're looking for. Filter functions are to output what sentinels are to termination.

```
(defun mymode--output-filter (process string)
  (let ((buffer (process-buffer process)))
    (when (buffer-live-p buffer)
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (forward-line 0)
        (when (mymode-looking-at-prompt)
          (do-something)
          (goto-char (point-max)))))))
```

Look at the manual or at many examples that come with Emacs (`grep` for `process-filter` in the `.el` files).

Register your filter function with

```
(set-process-filter 'mymode--output-filter)
```

#### The comint interface

Comint defines a filter function which does a few things:

- Switch to the buffer that should contain the process output.
- Run the functions in the list `comint-preoutput-filter-functions`, passing them the new text as an argument.
- Perform some ad hoc duplicate prompt elimination, based on `comint-prompt-regexp`.
- Insert the process output at the end of the buffer
- Run the functions in the list `comint-output-filter-functions`, passing them the new text as an argument.

Given that your mode is based on comint, you should register your filter in `comint-output-filter-functions`. You should set `comint-prompt-regexp` to match your prompt. I don't think Comint has a built-in facility to detect a complete output chunk (i.e. between two prompts), but it can help. The marker `comint-last-input-end` is set at the end of the last input chunk. You have a new output chunk when the end of the last prompt is after `comint-last-input-end`. How to find the end of the last prompt depends on the version of Emacs:

- Up to 24.3, the overlay `comint-last-prompt-overlay` spans the last prompt.
- Since 24.4, the variable `comint-last-prompt` contains markers to the start and end of the last prompt.

```
(defun mymode--comint-output-filter (string)
  (let ((start (marker-position comint-last-input-end))
        (end (if (boundp 'comint-last-prompt-overlay)
                 (and comint-last-prompt-overlay (overlay-start comint-last-prompt-overlay))
               (and comint-last-prompt (cdr comint-last-prompt))))
  (when (and start end (< start end))
    (let ((new-output-chunk (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
      ...)))
```

You may want to add protections in case the process emits output in a sequence other than {receive input, emit output, display prompt}.

Comment: The variable  comint-last-prompt-overlay does not seem to be defined in Emacs 25 in comint.el. Is it from somewhere else?

Comment: @JohnKitchin That part of comint changed in 24.4, I'd written my answer for 24.3. I've added a post-24.4 method.

Comment: Minor update regarding "duplicate prompt elimination": that code was removed in 2019, and apparently it never worked anyway: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/c0936672876bccc