# Asynchrony when collecting output in a process buffer?

Tags: process

I want to capture output from a process buffer. This is not a duplicate of [How do I reliably get output from a process?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30047/how-do-i-reliably-get-output-from-a-process) because that questioner is presupposing `comint` and an architecture for a function that returns the output. My question is at a lower level.

My theory was to get the value
of `point`
before sending a command string to the process buffer, call that value `p1`; send the command; get the
new value of `point`, call it `p2`, then call `(buffer-substring p1 p2)` to get
the output.

My theory works when sequentially executed in the REPL in the
`*scratch*` buffer. The commands don't work when sequentially executed in a
`progn` or in a `let*`.

I started off doing my theory in a `let*`. I'm using `shell` just as an example, the real target is another interpreter, so `async-shell-command` won't solve my real problem.

```
(with-current-buffer "*shell*"
  (let* (( p1   (point))
         ( _    (process-send-string "*shell*" "date\n"))
         ( p2   (point))
         ( text (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2)))
    `((p1 ,p1) (p2 ,p2) (text ,text))
    ))
```

> ((p1 326) (p2 326) (text ""))

and it didn't work. I am evaling everything in the `*scratch*` buffer with
<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>, using `*scratch*` like a traditional
lisp REPL.

I unrolled everything into separate calls setting global variables to investigate
why it didn't work, and discovered that it *DOES* work if I run the commands
sequentially in the REPL:

Here, I execute each line independently and show
the output:

```
(setq p1 (with-current-buffer "*shell*" (point)))
```

> 275

```
(process-send-string "*shell*" "date\n")
```

> nil

```
(setq p2 (with-current-buffer "*shell*" (point)))
```

> 326

```
(with-current-buffer "*shell*"
  (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2))
```

> "date
>      Sat Sep 15 10:47:38 PDT 2018
>
> ~ ⌚ 10:47:38
>      $ "

That's great. My theory is not completely crazy. Now, package that all back up in a `let*`, just in baby steps.
First, just put it all  in a `progn`, so that instead of four
commands, I will just have one:

```
(progn (setq p1 (with-current-buffer "*shell*" (point)))
       (process-send-string "*shell*" "date\n")
       (setq p2 (with-current-buffer "*shell*" (point)))
       (setq text (with-current-buffer "*shell*"
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2)))
       `((p1 ,p1) (p2 ,p2) (text ,text))
       )
```

> ((p1 473) (p2 473) (text ""))

Now it doesn't work.

To summarize: the commands work when sequentially executed in the REPL in the
`*scratch*` buffer. The commands don't work when sequentially executed in a
`progn` or in a `let*`.

There is some asynchrony going on that I don't understand and don't know how to
manage. The first call to `point`, the call that sets the value of `p1`, somehow
happens *after* the call to `process-send-string`, even though I explicitly call
`point` before calling `process-send-string`. `p1` has the same value before and
after the call of `process-send-string`, and that value is at the end of the
buffer. There is no way that the first call of `point` can clairvoyantly know
what the value of `point` will be after processing the command, so the call of
`point` must happen after the call of `process-send-string`, or else some
magical updating is going on, or some kind of lazy evaluation.

My questions are:

1. (this is what I really want) What is the right way to collect output from a
   command buffer?
2. Out of curiosity, what about this hidden asynchrony? How and where is it
   documented? How could I work my way around it?

Comment: Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Output from Processes` and especially `(elisp)Accepting Output`

Comment: Link [Accepting output](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accepting-Output.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs reads output from processes only when it is idle, or certain
functions are called.

The first condition occurs, when you evaluate the expressions one
after the other and that's why you notice the process's output in this
case.

One of the mentioned functions is `accept-process-output`, which, as
its name suggest, makes Emacs read some output from processes.  And if
you insert a call to that function in-between sending to the process
and reading the value of point the second time, you should see it
having been changed.

But in order to reliably capture a process's output you additionally
need some form of synchronization, i.e. some way of knowing, that the
process's output has been fully received, i.e. a protocol.